# Visual Studio hangs when IronPython code executes programmatically

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a question about executing IronPython code programmatically via C#. I use IronPython 2.7.6.3. My code looks like this:

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = IPython.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scriptScope = Engine.CreateScope();

scriptScope.ImportModule("clr");

scriptEngine.Execute("import clr", scriptScope);
scriptEngine.Execute("import System", scriptScope);

scriptEngine.Execute("clr.AddReference('System.Core')", scriptScope);
scriptEngine.Execute("clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)", scriptScope);

scriptEngine.Execute("from System import *", scriptScope);

ScriptSource scriptSource = scriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(string_with_ironpython_code);

scriptSource.Execute(scriptScope);
```

My IronPython code contains usage of IEnumerable extension methods from System.Linq namespace, that's why I'm using System.Core and clr.ImportExtensions("") method. And when I run this code my Visual Studio hangs at this line:

```
scriptSource.Execute(scriptScope);
```

I've waited for 10 minutes and then just stopped the process. But if I remove adding reference to System.Core.dll and import extensions then I got error that I can't access to IEnumerable extension methods. By the way, when I execute another IronPython code, where there is no usage of IEnumerable extensions methods and I have no need write this lines:

```
scriptEngine.Execute("clr.AddReference('System.Core')", scriptScope);
scriptEngine.Execute("clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)", scriptScope);
```

everythings works fine.
So my questions is: Am I doing something wrong with adding reference and import extensions? Or why my Visual Studio hangs when I try execute scriptSource with adding this reference?

P.S. When I wrote IronPython code in Visual Studio and run this *.py file from Visual Studio - everything worked fine.